# How to access avplayer video buffer frames while video is playing

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, quartz-core

If I have a video file that is playing, what is the most efficient way to add a video filter? I know I can use generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes, but I'd like to do it in real time.

[RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) in Apple's Docs show how you can do it for live video before the buffer frame is displayed to the user. I'd like to do the same thing for a video that is already recorded, while it is playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "SCPlayer" - subclass of AVPlayer from https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder
It provides great way to perform groups of CIFilters, so you can even change it when video is playing :) Here you also can find custom ExportSession to save video with filter.
To use this you need to init your video as AVAsset.